# How can we create splunk alerts using config files?

Tags: alert, splunk, saved-searches

I am new to splunk and I am trying to configure alerts using configuration files, so I used the following savedsearches.conf file but I can't see the new alert in the UI:

```html
[Gurobitest]
# send an email notification
action.email = 1
action.email.to = <my email address>
action.email.useNSSubject = 1

alert.suppress = 0
alert.track = 0

cron_schedule = 0/1 * * * *

#search for results in the last day
dispatch.earliest_time = -1d
dispatch.latest_time = now

display.events.fields = ["host","source","sourcetype","latitude"]
display.page.search.mode = verbose
display.visualizations.charting.chart = area
display.visualizations.type = mapping

enableSched = 1

request.ui_dispatch_app = search
request.ui_dispatch_view = search
search =  host=<hostname> sourcetype=gurobi_expiration
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you restart Splunk after making changes to the config file?  Changes don't appear in the UI until after a restart.

Comment: yes I restarted splunk but still can't see it

Comment: why do you want to send an *Alert* every minute?!

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues preventing the alert from being displayed. The first is the `cron_schedule` setting. Splunk doesn't recognize `0/1 * * * *` as a valid cron expression so the alert is ignored.  There should be a log message to that effect in `index=_internal`.  Changing the schedule to `* * * * *` fixed it for me, but that's a short-term solution since it's rarely necessary to run an alert every minute (who will respond that quickly?).

The other issue is the missing `counttype` setting.  It defaults to "always", which makes the search a report rather than an alert.  Changing it to "number of events" makes the alert show up on my system.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the savedsearches.conf file as you suggested but still can't see the alert

```html
[Gurobitest]
# send an email notification
action.email = 1
action.email.to = <my_email_address>
action.email.useNSSubject = 1

alert.suppress = 0
alert.track = 0

cron_schedule = 0 23 * * *

counttype = number of events
quantity = 0
relation = greater than

#search for results in the last day
dispatch.earliest_time = -1d
dispatch.latest_time = now

display.events.fields = ["host","source","sourcetype","latitude"]
display.page.search.mode = verbose
display.visualizations.charting.chart = area
display.visualizations.type = mapping

enableSched = 1

request.ui_dispatch_app = search
request.ui_dispatch_view = search
search = sourcetype=gurobi_expiration
```

Comment: How and where are you looking for the alert?  It should be in `Settings->Searches, reports, and alerts`.  You may need to sign in as an admin to see it until the permissions are adjusted.

Comment: same place from where I can see alerts created manually

Comment: app/search/alerts

Comment: Try the method I suggested for listing alerts.  Looking search->alerts will work only if the alert was added to the search/local/savedsearches.conf file.

Comment: I created new savedsearches.conf file under /opt/splunkforwarder/etc/apps/search/local with the same content, and was checking in the UI in Settings->Searches, reports, and alerts but same thing can't see it :(

Comment: Somethings wrong there.  `/opt/splunkforwarder` implies a Universal Forwarder, but they don't have a UI.  Are you sure you're looking at the same instance you are modifying?

Comment: yeah, I am trying to configure the alert on the same instance sending logs to splunk UI, we can't configure alerts remotely same as we did for data sources? as I added an inputs.conf file in the same location to collect logs on that instance and I can see these logs in splunk UI

Comment: You can configure alerts on any instance, but they won't work on a forwarder.  The proper place for them is a search head.  Forwarders send data so that's why configuring an input there makes the data visible somewhere else.  It doesn't work that way with other configs, however.

Comment: okay thanks a lot Sir, so the best way to configure alerts for forwarders is to create it manually from the UI as we can't configure it from the forwarder itself, right?

Comment: The UI is the easiest way to do it.